# Calling directive again when div visible

Tags: angularjs

I have following requirement.
when page load,model.isValidUserType() is false so my div is not visible but directive 'my-directive' getting called.
But user did some actions and model.isValidUserType() return true and my div is visible. But here my-directive is not getting called.

So how to call my-directive again my div is visible.

```
<div ng-show="model.isValidUserType() ===true">
    <div>
        <section class="abc" apply-check id='home'>
            <progress-card></progress-card>
        </section>
    </div>


</div>
```

I can not use ng-if as it failed for some other condition. Any other way to fix it.?

Comment: You have to show your controller logic

Comment: try to change `ng-show` to `ng-if`. `ng-if` add the HTML to DOM each time is true. `ng-show` just show/hidden rendered elements. Beside this, you'll need to post your logic.

Comment: Can you share these 'other condition'? Ng-if should be the way to go, so maybe there's something else that can be done about the other condition. Also you talk about `my-directive`, but there's no such directive in your code.

Comment: This is akward - why run directive when element is not visible if when it becomes visible you want to run it again? I mean you can do it ofc, just think that you are missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `<div ng-show="model.isValidUserType() ===true">`

with    `<div ng-if="model.isValidUserType() ===true">`

Comment: `<div ng-if="model.isValidUserType() ===true">` would be better or `<div ng-if="(model.isValidUserType() ===true)">`

Comment: Right I've just copied and pasted ;) What I've mean was to switch to ng-if. Anyway thanks for noticing that

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ng-if in place of ng-show.

```
<div ng-if="model.isValidUserType() ===true">
<div>
    <section class="abc" apply-check id='home'>
        <progress-card></progress-card>
    </section>
</div>
```